# C# Generics: 'x' is a 'type' but used like a 'variable'

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

For some reason, this code won't compile:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
_sectionStories = serializer.Deserialize < IDictionary<int, ObservableCollection<Story>>(new JTokenReader(contents));
```

The error:

> Error 91  'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary>'
>   is a 'type' but is used like a
>   'variable'

What am I doing wrong here? I feel like I'm missing something basic.

Comment: maybe it should be _sectionStories = serializer.Deserialize < IDictionary<int, ObservableCollection<Story>>>(new JTokenReader(contents));

Comment: @dkson - Yup, a > is clearly missing here since he has 3 <'s and 2 >'s ;)

Comment: As @dkson said you missed `>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like a typo. I see three `<` but only two `>`.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a `>`.

For illustrative purposes, I have matched up the `<`s and `>`s below:

```
_sectionStories = serializer.Deserialize<
                     IDictionary<
                        int,
                        ObservableCollection<Story>
                     >
                  >(new JTokenReader(contents)));
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the good synthaxe is :

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        _sectionStories = serializer.Deserialize < IDictionary<int, ObservableCollection<Story>>>(new JTokenReader(contents));
```